# Can you load more files (instead of csf.allow) in CSF? like *.conf in Apache?

Tags: iptables, centos5, csf

Currently I keep all of the blocked IPs for my CSF firewall in a single "csf.deny" file which is getting difficult to maintain. In an attempt to organize things a bit more (since not ALL of the IP blocks I deny changes frequently), I was wondering if CSF has the ability, like Apache with it's *.conf files, to load multiple files of my choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that but you can use an `Include` statement in your `/etc/csf/csf.deny` file

```
Include /etc/csf/csf.denytoo
```

Perhaps you can use that to help organise your blocked IP addresses ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I posted the answer and accepted it (or had to wait before accepting it). This is weird that you could edit my posts and delete the original answer I gave. But yes, you are right. I can use Include to manage other IP's and have done so since posting this question.

Comment: I haven't deleted any answers - I can't do that. There are no answers to this question that have been deleted either. Did you ask the question elsewhere ?